# Unable to run tutorial script

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to run the Google Docs CreateAndSendDocument example function, I get a dialog box saying " needs your permission to access your data on Google".  The dialog buttons are "Review Permissions" and Cancel (no "Continue" or "Allow" option as described in the tutorial is ever shown).  After selecting Review Permissions, I am asked for a google account (even though I was logged in to my account).  I pick my account, then I get another dialog box saying "This app isn't verified", with a "Back to Safety" button.  There is also a link for "Learn More" if I am the developer and want to remove this screen.

It does not seem like I should need to learn OAuth and set that up in order to run a tutorial.  What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: Click "Learn More"

Comment: Scroll down to a message then ends in (Unsafe)  I think it states "Advanced"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Scripts cannot be given Authorization or Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317412/google-app-scripts-cannot-be-given-authorization-or-permission)

Comment: Thank you.  A little different scenario, but the same problem.