# How do I give my Google Script access for onFormSubmit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to have my Google Script use the `OnFormSubmit` trigger.

When I try to use it, it says I do not have permission.

When I try to get permission, it says Google has not verified yet.

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: When it says Google has not verified yet, there is a link in the bottom: **Advanced**, click on it and then click on **Continue to _appname_ (unsafe)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Scripts cannot be given Authorization or Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317412/google-app-scripts-cannot-be-given-authorization-or-permission)