# 'The script does not have permission' errors - calendar API

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm trying to develop a Google Apps Script and I tried to include the following lines and they both raise the following errors:

> The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds) at addToCalendar(Code:104)

for the line

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
```

and

> You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets at updateVolunteerSheet(Code:96)

for the line

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YJBRfz0rDIajlZjF35eRP8-lepdf2dJpzZea0cRXc1k");
```

I tried to get the restrictive scopes approved for my app but I don't have a domain because this is just supposed to be to run these custom functions so I don't have the required Application Homepage link and Application Privacy Policy link thus not able to get permissions. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Scripts cannot be given Authorization or Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317412/google-app-scripts-cannot-be-given-authorization-or-permission)