# This operation is not supported. An error in google tables when a script is executed from under another user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Using scripts in google tables, I work with google forms. Using my main account, which is located in the domain of the organization to which I belong, everything is fine.

When I use the new Google account, then the script crashes with an error:

> "This operation is not supported." In the Google tab: "Security Check"
> on the second account, the application is indicated as made by
> "Unverified Developer".

An error occurs when trying to edit a form created by a script.

The code is called by a `POST` request with JSON parameters. Queries are allowed to anonymous users.

I tried to check the box to enable unverified applications

```
var form = FormApp.create(NewForm.name);        
form.setRequireLogin(false)
    .setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId())
    .setDescription(NewForm.description)
    .setConfirmationMessage('Спасибо за ваши ответы!');
```

expect the script to work without errors

Comment: Are both accounts part of the same domain? and also, whewre are you running the script from?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49317729)

Comment: @AMolina The first account is in my organization’s domain. The second account does not belong to this domain. The second account was registered using Google’s usual means.

Comment: @TheMaster Even after confirming in the "advanced" menu and allowing the use of unsafe applications, this did not help.

Comment: Since the accounts are on different  domains it might be an issue with permissions, is your script bound to any particular file in the first account (the one in the organization's domain)?

Comment: @AMolina Forms and Google tables that are processed from the script are on the same account.
Everything works on the first account.
I transferred the functionality from the first account to the second.
The second account has problems. The scripts, table, and forms are the same, but the error "This operation is not supported." when the script is editing the new form that it created.
The difference between accounts:
The second account is not an approved developer.
The first account is paid in the domain of my organization.

Comment: How is the web app published? Try setting "Execute as" to `Me` and "Access" to `Anyone even anonymous`

Comment: @TheMaster I originally Deploy it as a web application with these settings

Comment: Explain how the second account runs the script. By POST request? Where are the form, tables that you're edit? In the first account's Google drive? Or the second account's Google drive?

Comment: @TheMaster The table, form, and script are on the second account and they are in no way associated with the duplicate set of tables, forms and scripts on the first account. The script receives data on a POST request and processes it with a table and created forms on the same account as it is. I developed the functionality on the first account, but it should work on a third-party account - the second.

Comment: Could you try running the script directly from the script editor from the second account providing [a dummy `e` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067)